# Access to HDFS HA cluster from ClickHouse failed with the error HdfsConfigNotFound

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability, clickhouse

I created an HDFS based table over Clickhouse. My HDFS cluster had HA on, but an error occurred when I was querying the table I created
myDDl:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userItemLable ON CLUSTER cluster_1st( 
label int,
length int,
duration int
)ENGINE=HDFS('hdfs://cluster1/test/','')
```

errorcode:

```sh
Code: 210. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Unable to connect to HDFS: InvalidParameter: Cannot parse URI: hdfs://cluster1, missing port or invalid HA configuration Caused by: HdfsConfigNotFound: Config key: dfs.ha.namenodes.cluster1 not found.
```

---

I have tried copy hdfs-site.xml to */etc/clickhouse-server* file path, but the problem has not been solved.

Then I renamed this file to *hdfs-client.xml*, the result is the same.

Finally, In *config.xml*, I did not find how to configure HDFS HA.

Comment: related discussion on github [How do I use an HDFS engine in HA mode #8159](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8159)

Comment: as I understood the problem on Hadoop side, try to config it as described here [HDB query fails after NameNode HA was enabled](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/HDB-query-fails-after-NameNode-HA-was-enabled?language=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

You can use port 8020 with the HDFS ip and path.
It is working for me.
example :
CREATE TABLE ELM.hdfs_table (name String, value UInt32) ENGINE=HDFS('hdfs://168.11.12.103:8020/user/nirakar/clickhouse/hdfs_table', 'TSV');

INSERT INTO ELM.hdfs_table VALUES ('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 4);

Note: Make sure your local server /etc/hosts should have IP address of the HDFS server.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to copy the file `[hdfs-site.xml]` to the path `[/etc/clickhouse-server/hdfs-client.xml]`

Second, edit the file `[/etc/init.d/clickhouse-server]` and add the following config:

`[export LIBHDFS3_CONF=/etc/clickhouse-server/hdfs-client.xml]`

after that, the file `[/etc/init.d/clickhouse-server]` should be like this:

```html
    sudo cat -n  /etc/init.d/clickhouse-server
    1  #!/bin/sh
    2  ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    3  # Provides:          clickhouse-server
    4  # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    5  # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    6  # Required-Start:    $network
    7  # Required-Stop:     $network
    8  # Short-Description: Yandex clickhouse-server daemon
    9  ### END INIT INFO
    10
    11  CLICKHOUSE_USER=clickhouse
    12  CLICKHOUSE_GROUP=${CLICKHOUSE_USER}
    13  SHELL=/bin/bash
    14  PROGRAM=clickhouse-server
    15  CLICKHOUSE_GENERIC_PROGRAM=clickhouse
    16  CLICKHOUSE_PROGRAM_ENV=""
    17  EXTRACT_FROM_CONFIG=${CLICKHOUSE_GENERIC_PROGRAM}-extract-from-config
    18  CLICKHOUSE_CONFDIR=/etc/$PROGRAM
    19  CLICKHOUSE_LOGDIR=/var/log/clickhouse-server
    20  CLICKHOUSE_LOGDIR_USER=root
    21  CLICKHOUSE_DATADIR=/var/lib/clickhouse
    22  if [ -d "/var/lock" ]; then
    23      LOCALSTATEDIR=/var/lock
    24  else
    25      LOCALSTATEDIR=/run/lock
    26  fi
    27
    28  if [ ! -d "$LOCALSTATEDIR" ]; then
    29      mkdir -p "$LOCALSTATEDIR"
    30  fi
    31
    32  CLICKHOUSE_BINDIR=/usr/bin
    33  CLICKHOUSE_CRONFILE=/etc/cron.d/clickhouse-server
    34  CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG=$CLICKHOUSE_CONFDIR/config.xml
    35  LOCKFILE=$LOCALSTATEDIR/$PROGRAM
    36  CLICKHOUSE_PIDDIR=/var/run/$PROGRAM
    37  CLICKHOUSE_PIDFILE="$CLICKHOUSE_PIDDIR/$PROGRAM.pid"
    38  # CLICKHOUSE_STOP_TIMEOUT=60 # Disabled by default. Place to /etc/default/clickhouse if you need.
    39
    40  export LIBHDFS3_CONF=/etc/clickhouse-server/hdfs-client.xml
```